# Why does an exception about ambigious controllers with attempted errorhandling mess up the pipeline?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8

I'm experimenting with some error handling, and this specific error seems to mess things up.

I have a HttpModule (see below) that subscribes to the HttpApplication.Error event handler, where I clear the errors and write some dummy response content.

This works fine with "normal" application errors, however when I get the error about ambiguous controllers, it goes into the handler as usual, but the changed response is totally ignored and the flow of execution in the pipeline seems to have some minor breakdown, creating a IIS subrequest to the same resources that goes outside of MVC, resulting in a IIS error page about that it can not list the directory, or that the file does not exist, depending on the original path of the request.

**To reproduce:**

1. Create a new templated MVC-project.
2. Add a new area and create a HomeController (this will conflict with the default HomeController)

Run the application and you should see a ASP.NET error page about ambiguous controllers.

3. Add the HttpModule provided below

Run the application, and this will result in a 403.14 IIS error page from the DirectoryListingModule.

4. Remove or rename the ambiguous controller in the new Area, but create a runtime error in the Index action for the default HomeController (e.g. DivideByZero).

Run the application, and this will result in a 200 response with "Hello world", as expected.

```
public class HttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.Error += HandleApplicationError;
    }

    private void HandleApplicationError(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        var server = ((HttpApplication)sender).Server;
        server.ClearError();
        response.Clear();
        response.Write("Hello world");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

What is happening here? Why do things break when I try to clear the errors and change the response when we get exceptions about ambiguous controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour depends on where the exception is thrown regarding the request handling pipeline.

- In case of the ambiguous controller, the routing system founds a route that matches the url and tries to get an IHttpHandler that will handle the request. However the exception is thrown trying to get that IHttpHandler, check this stack trace:

  ```
  at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerTypeWithinNamespaces(RouteBase route, String controllerName, HashSet`1 namespaces)
  at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerType(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
  at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory.GetControllerSessionBehavior(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetSessionStateBehavior(RequestContext requestContext)
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.System.Web.Routing.IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
  at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context)
  at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object s atder, Ev attArgs e)
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEv attExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
  ```

  As the routing module has not been able to get a handler, IIS will try to handle it with other modules. This means it will try to serve the request using the `DirectoryListingModule` and `StaticFileModule` which are enabled by default on IIS.
- When an exception is thrown inside a controller action, the request already had an IHttpHandler assigned which is processing the request. Check the different stack trace:

  ```
  at WebApplication3.Controllers.HomeController.ThrowError() at g:\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 32
  at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
  at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c()
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e()
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19()
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
  ```

  So in this case, if an exception is thrown the system won´t try to serve the request using other modules like `DirectoryListingModule` and `StaticFileModule`

Regarding your error handler, in the scenario of the ambiguous controller you need a way to prevent the system from finding another IHttpHandler that will handle the request (as the error was raised trying to get an MvcHandler). 
One could also argue that such an error (an ambiguous controller name) is a serious bug that should be catched at development time and never should make it to production.

In any case, there are a few alternatives like transferring to static html files `server.Transfer("Error500.html");` or brute force ones like completing the request at the end of your error handler `((HttpApplication)sender).CompleteRequest();`.

So for example one option might be transferring to a static 500 error file when the current IHttpHandler is null, keeping your current handler code otherwise:

```
private void HandleApplicationError(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var application = sender as HttpApplication;        
    var server = application.Server;

    if (application.Context.CurrentHandler == null)
    {
        server.Transfer("Error500.html");
    }
    else
    {
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        server.ClearError();
        response.Clear();
        response.Write("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good, but there is one thing that I still do not understand, and that is the fact that the "UrlRoutingModule-4.0" results in a default error page if we disable the custom error handling, and it does not try DirectoryListingModule or StaticFileModule. If the behavior you describe is caused by a failed attempt by IIS to find a handler, why is this only triggered when I try to clear the response? Am I by clearing the response somehow causing IIS to misunderstand something about what just happened?

Comment: Maybe it's because when I don't clear the the errors, IIS will have the error registered in the pipeline after the failed attempt to get a handler, and will use this to produce the error page in another handler, independent of the original failed attempt of getting a handler. Thus, when I clear the errors, IIS simply don't trigger the error page module and continues to search...

Comment: Without calling `server.ClearError` the error would scalate until it is finally handled by asp producing the yellow screen of death. So if you remove your error handling code, or comment the line calling `ClearError` you will see the YSOD

Comment: Do you know exactly how this error is escalated? Is it all handled within the UrlRoutingModule? I'm looking at the trace files, but can't make much out of it. Wish there was a more explicit way to follow the flow through IIS.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the internal exception handling process of asp net that causes the YSOD but I guess it would be part of the default asp net request pipeline. If you add an `Application_Error` and `Application_EndRequest` methods to global.asax you will see the end request is fired after the error one and the response was cleared and replaced with the YSOD, so there might be a global module subscribed to the OnError event. (I am not familiar with this code so I might be wrong)